# What does fornicating the odds mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

In this paragraph of **Pulp** novel of **Charles Bukowski**:

> I lit my cigarette, took a drag. Then I followed him. I have Red a goodbye nod, then stepped into the street. Just in time to see him get into an '89 Fiat **at the curb**. And who was parked right behind him? My Bug was parked right behind him, What luck! **Talk about fornicating the odds!** First time I had found **curb parking** in months!

First question: what does **fornicating the odds** mean and whats is its origin?

Second question: I know what does **curb** mean, but what does **curb parking** mean here and **to park at the curb**?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's new to me. From context, it must mean 'beating the odds', that is benefiting from an unlikely event, one not favored by the odds.

Parking at the curb is leaving one's automobile at the the side of the street, rather than paying to park it in a parking garage. It can be hard to find an empty space on a busy city street - hence, unlikely, against the odds.